# Pattern matching Over A Nested Data Constructor

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

For the following code I keep on getting a compiler error because I am writing (List _) and it is trying to pattern match over the list. How can I fix tihs?

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | Empty

instance Monad List where
    Empty >>= _ = Empty 
    Cons x (List _) >>= f = f x
```

Answer (score 7):

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | Empty
```

This defines a *type constructor* `List` with two *data constructors* `Cons` and `Empty`. `Cons` has two fields, one of type `a`, and one of type `List a`—which may, in turn, be either `Empty` or a `Cons`, and so on.

So when you write:

```
Cons x (List _) >>= f = f x
```

The compiler is looking for a *data* constructor called `List` to pattern-match on, and there isn’t one—hence the error. If you just want to ignore the field, write:

```
Cons x _ >>= f = f x
```

Now of course this isn’t a proper `Monad` instance for `List`—it’s more like the one for `Maybe`—but I’ll leave you to work through that on your own.